# Spark Java program to read the table from snowflake

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I could find this:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Read-a-table-from-Snowflake-on-AWS-using-Spark

Is there something for Spark programs written in Java to connect to snowflake and read the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create it on my own.
https://github.com/ashutoshsharmaindia/SparkJavaSnowFlake.git

This doesn't require creating any table etc...just use the existing Snowflake table to read the data in.

Answer (score -1):

A quick review of the [Overview of the Spark Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-overview.html) shows Java as an option for Spark with Snowflake. The code presented in [Using the Spark Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html) is for Scala but should be straightforward to modify for Java.

You may find this [Spark by Example: Java- Create Snowflake table programmatically](https://sparkbyexamples.com/snowflake/java-create-snowflake-table-programmatically/) helpful.

Comment: That's just Java NOT spark